# Couchbase sync gateway return forbidden response on document deletion?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Following is the sync function used in the sync gateway.

```
function (doc, oldDoc) {
if (doc._deleted == true) return;
....rest of the validations
}
```

As per the above function, there is no validation in document deletion. But the sync gateway returns a forbidden error when trying to delete documents. Can some one help on this